# Separate Legends for Multiple ChartAreas in Single Chart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asp.net-charts

I cannot seem to get my individual subcharts (contained within my single chart object) to host individual legends for their respective data series. I would like to know if this is possible and, if so, what I can adjust in my code to achieve this effect.

Thanks for your help

Code is as follows:

```
chart_MyChart.Legends.Clear();

ChartArea chartArea_MyData = new ChartArea("My Data");
ChartArea chartArea_YourData = new ChartArea("Your Data");
ChartArea chartArea_OtherData = new ChartArea("Other Data");

chart_MyChart.ChartAreas.Clear();
chart_MyChart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea_MyData);
chart_MyChart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea_YourData);
chart_MyChart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea_OtherData);             

/* Chart Area: My Data */
Series series01 = this.chart_MyChart.Series.Add("My first series");
series01.ChartArea = chartArea_MyData.Name;
Series series02 = this.chart_MyChart.Series.Add("My second series");
series02.ChartArea = chartArea_MyData.Name;

Legend legend01 = new Legend(series01.Name);
Legend legend02 = new Legend(series02.Name);

legend01.DockedToChartArea = chartArea_MyData.Name;
legend02.DockedToChartArea = chartArea_MyData.Name;

chart_MyChart.Legends.Add(legend01);
chart_MyChart.Legends.Add(legend02);

/* Chart Area: Your Data */
Series series03 = this.chart_MyChart.Series.Add("Your first series");
series03.ChartArea = chartArea_YourData.Name;
Series series04 = this.chart_MyChart.Series.Add("Your second series");
series04.ChartArea = chartArea_YourData.Name;

Legend legend03 = new Legend(series03.Name);
Legend legend04 = new Legend(series04.Name);

legend03.DockedToChartArea = chartArea_YourData.Name;
legend04.DockedToChartArea = chartArea_YourData.Name;

chart_MyChart.Legends.Add(legend03);
chart_MyChart.Legends.Add(legend04);

/* Chart Area: Other Data */
Series series05 = this.chart_MyChart.Series.Add("Other series");
series05.ChartArea = chartArea_OtherData.Name;

Legend legend05 = new Legend(series05.Name);

legend05.DockedToChartArea = chartArea_OtherData.Name;

chart_MyChart.Legends.Add(legend05);

foreach(Legend legend in chart_MyChart.Legends)
{
    legend.IsDockedInsideChartArea = true;
}

foreach(widget myWidget in some.widget)
{
    series01.Points.AddXY(widget.timeStamp, widget.data1);
    series02.Points.AddXY(widget.timeStamp, widget.data2);
    series03.Points.AddXY(widget.timeStamp, widget.data3);
    series04.Points.AddXY(widget.timeStamp, widget.data4);
    series05.Points.AddXY(widget.timeStamp, widget.data5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance you seem to be missing the association between the series and the Legend this is from the WebSamples project that you can download [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61), it really helps to see a full source examples.

In the MultiLegends section, the code looks like this:

```
            // Add a second legend
            Legend secondLegend = new Legend("Second");
            secondLegend.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(((System.Byte)(220)), ((System.Byte)(255)), ((System.Byte)(255)), ((System.Byte)(255)));
            secondLegend.BorderColor = Color.Gray;
            secondLegend.Font = this.Chart1.Legends["Default"].Font;

            this.Chart1.Legends.Add(secondLegend);

            // Associate Series 2 with the second legend 
            this.Chart1.Series["Series 2"].Legend = "Second";
```

The only thing that I didn't see in your code is that last line of association.

Comment: Thanks for the extra reference